# Using Connection String in Application Properties for Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dataset, connection-string

I've been using DataSets and TableAdapters in my C# .NET applications for a while now, and I'm looking at making the switch to Entity Framework. Like many companies, my company uses a development server, a test server, and a production server. With DataSets I was able to change the server by editing the connection string under `Project -> [project name here] Properties... -> Settings -> Connection string` and editing the server information. From everything I've been able to deduce about Entity Framework, it uses a more static connection string located in the *app.config* file.

Is there a way to attach the entity framework to the Connection string in the application settings or use code to edit the connection?

I've written the following code to change a connection string before connection to the server, could this be modified to work with the Entity Framework connection?

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
                var connectionStringsSection = (ConnectionStringsSection)config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
                connectionStringsSection.ConnectionStrings[1].ConnectionString = @"server connection goes here";
                config.Save();
                ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

Answer (score 0):

DbContext - base class responsible to access data in EF has a constructor that accepts a DbConnection parameter with possibility to set classic ConnectionString which you can build in any way you consider appropriate.
You can build it in runtime or just have a connection string  in app.config with name of your class that it is derived from DbContext

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/gg696604(v=vs.113).aspx

```
<add name="SuperDbContext" connectionString="lala"/>

public class SuperDbContext : DbContext
{
   //code here
}
```